# Don't match if character is present in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to test if an input field contains a valid "slug" (a string that can only contain dashes and lowercase letters, used in URLs)

My issue is that the user can write a valid slug, but then they can write invalid characters after the valid ones, and it will still match.

My regex looks like this: `/[a-z\-]+/`

This should match: `'my-slug-is-valid'`

But this should not match: `'my-SLUG-is not valid'`

Yet when I test the regex against that last string, `true` is returned.

```
var re = /[a-z\-]+/,
    str = 'my-SLUG-is not valid';

if (re.test(str) && str !== '') {
    console.log('Valid');
}
```

Is it possible to return false if there are characters present that are not part of the char-class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to match the *entire* string.  In that case, add anchors to the regex:

```
re = /^[a-z\-]+$/
```

Comment: Also matches `my-slug-is-`

Answer (score 1):

```
var re = /^[a-z-]+$/;
```

You need the **^** and **$** to anchor the beginning and end of the string.